# Installing only possible with iommu=soft

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

So I got this new laptop, Ideapad 330s with Ryzen 5 2500u, Vega 8 gpu(integrated), and 4 gb of ram. It comes with windows 10 preinstalled which is fine after removing all of the bloatware, but I wanted to dual boot xubuntu for a better programming enviroment. So I freed 300 gb from disk management on windows and then proceeded to install xubuntu from a usb stick.

I got to grub but after choosing either try live or install I got a black screen. After trying some stuff out, I did some research online and found out I could only get to try live or install by passing the iommu=soft as a kernel parameter.

I tried understanding what this means but absence of computer architecture knowledge won't let me. Is this fine? Will this have any impact on my laptop? Will this kernel parameter be needed after installation? Also heard maybe battery will drop faster, is this true? Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's fine and it's needed also after installing. No, it has nothing to do - directly - with battery. *maybe battery will drop faster* ... Really? Compared to what, a non-booting system?